# returning reference to local temporary object c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Overload the relational operator ==for the class stackTypethat returns trueiftwo stacks of the same type are the same; falseif otherwise.

my code:

```
template <class Type>
const stackType<Type>& stackType<Type>::operator ==
(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    if (this->stackTop != otherStack.stackTop)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
        if (this->list[i] != otherStack.list[i])
            return false;
    return true;
} //end operator==
```

I'm receiving a returning reference to local temporary object warning and from what i understand is that it's being destroyed once the function scope ends. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solving this warning?

Comment: Don't return reference to local temporary.

Comment: To avoid the warning just don't do it ... You can safely return ref to attribute or allocated memory (new).

Comment: @fievel but why allocate anything? The asker clearly needs to return bool and screwed up the return type.

Comment: @user4581301 exact I vote for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your operator to return a `const stackType<Type>&`, bt then you return `true` or `false`. The compiler tries to convert `true` and `false` to `const stackType<Type>&`, and then return it. That’s probably not what you intended - rather declare it to return a `bool`.

Even if the conversion would work, the reference is to a local variable, which gives UB.

Comment: Correct, it was meant to be a bool, but i still get a returning to local temp. How do I I not return to local temp?

Comment: Did you define it to return a `bool&`? Don't do that, never with elementary data types. Otherwise, the error must come from somewhere else in the code.